# Display multiple selectbox and radio button values values in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site that allows users to "guess / predict" the result of a sports match

To give you an idea what I am trying to achieve have a look at the following image:

[image]

The selected teams gets displayed at the bottom of the page (as you can see on the bottom circle of the image)

**What Im trying to do**

Im trying to modify the script to not only display the selected team at the bottom of the page but ***also the selected score***

**Example**

*Chiefs by 12*

[Have a look at my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/2qed0o7g/) to get an idea of what I am doing, if anyone can help me to modify my script to include the score aswell it would be tremendously appreciated

**My Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function(e) {
    //clear the div
    $('#dispPicks').html('');
    //update the div
    $(':radio:checked').each(function(ind, ele) {
      $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() + '<br/>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Shaks" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Hurricanes" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Draw" />

<select>
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Crusaders" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Pioneers" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Draw" />
<select>
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Chelsea" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Liverpool" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Draw" />
<select>
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

[**Fiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/2qed0o7g/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put related radio buttons and select box in a `div` and assign a class to it lets say `team`, then read checked radio button and value of select box in the same div as checked radio button belogs to. see below code -

HTML

```
<div class="team">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Shaks" />
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Hurricanes" />
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Draw" />

    <select>
            <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
    <input type="radio" name="bar" value="Crusaders" />
    <input type="radio" name="bar" value="Pioneers" />
    <input type="radio" name="bar" value="Draw" />
    <select>
            <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
    <input type="radio" name="wow" value="Chelsea" />
    <input type="radio" name="wow" value="Liverpool" />
    <input type="radio" name="wow" value="Draw" />
    <select>
            <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio, select').change(function (e) {
        //clear the div
        $('#dispPicks').html('');
        //update the div
        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            var selectBoxVal = $(this).closest('div.team').find('select').val();
            selectBoxVal = selectBoxVal!=''? "By "+selectBoxVal:selectBoxVal;
            $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() +"  "+selectBoxVal+ '<br/>');
        });
    });
});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2qed0o7g/9/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, im gonna give it a go on my site and let you know

Answer (score 2):

I've made a few changes which I thought were essential:

**1.** since a team can't win by the score of 0, 0 is out of the select boxes

**2.** I gave all the `select` tags a `data-name` according to its radio button's names

and here we go **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2qed0o7g/8/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio, select').change(function (e) {
        //clear the div
        $('#dispPicks').html('');
        //update the div
        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            var name=$(this).attr('name');
            if($(this).val()=='Draw'){
                $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val());
            }
            else{
                $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() + ' by '+$('select[data-name='+name+']').val() + '<br>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you to use more id's and names.
This is what i made for you, it just basic to let you understand what i mean:

```js
 $(':radio').change(function(e) {
   x = $(this).attr('name');
   y = $('input[name=' + x + ']:checked').val();
   $("#" + x).html(y);
 });

 $("select").change(function() {
   x = $(this).attr('name');
   y = $(this).val();
   $("#" + x).html(" by " + y);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pick1" value="Shaks" />
<input type="radio" name="pick1" value="Hurricanes" />
<input type="radio" name="pick1" value="Draw" />
<select name="howMuch1">
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" name="pick2" value="Chelsea" />
<input type="radio" name="pick2" value="Liverpool" />
<input type="radio" name="pick2" value="Draw" />
<select name="howMuch2">
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<div id="picks">
  <br /><span id="pick1"></span><span id="howMuch1"></span>

  <br /><span id="pick2"></span><span id="howMuch2"></span>

</div>
```

On event (change) we make x our target and y our value.. rest is a case of put it right ;)